# Why is there an exponent 4 after the brackets in sp3?

Tags: orbitals, electronic-configuration

My professor wrote an electron configuration for carbon as: 1s<sup>2</sup> (sp<sup>3</sup>)<sup>4</sup>

I thought it was just 1s<sup>2</sup> sp<sup>3</sup> where did the <sup>4</sup> come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The electron configuration of carbon is canonically written as 1s<sup>2</sup>2s<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>2</sup>. What you now can do is invoke [orbital hybridization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation) and combine the electrons in the 2s and 2p orbitals. Then you get sp<sup>3</sup> hybrid orbitals with a total of 4 electrons in them. The 1s electrons stay where they are. To mark the new hybrid orbitals as separate, you put brackets around them.

You then end up with an electronic configuration of **1s<sup>2</sup>(2sp<sup>3</sup>)<sup>4</sup>**.